# Q: error C2227: left of '->listView1' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    MyForm2^ myform2 = gcnew MyForm2();
    String^ constring = L"datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
    MySqlConnection^ conDataBase = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand(
        "Update librarysystem.bookdetails set isbn = '" + this->textBox1->Text + 
            "', booktitle = '" + this->textBox2->Text + 
            "', bookauthor = '" + this->textBox3->Text + 
            "', bookcategory = '" + this->comboBox1->SelectedItem + 
            "', bookedition = '" + this->textBox5->Text + 
            "', booknumofcopies = '" + this->textBox4->Text + 
            "' where isbn =  '" + myform2->listView1->FocusedItem->ListView + "' ;", 
        conDataBase);
    MySqlDataReader^ myReader;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyForm2^ myform2 = gcnew MyForm2();
...
myform2->listView1->FocusedItem->ListView
```

There's something wrong with your declaration of MyForm2. Most likely is that you didn't `#include "MyForm2.h"`. You are probably also getting errors about `'MyForm2' : undeclared identifier`.

Comment: thankyou for the info, what should i do or how should i declare myform2 to myform16 because they should be connected for my listview tool